# Event-Specific Data with DataAvailable

Tags: matlab, event-handling

I am trying to include specific data into the EventData of a DataAvailable listener, but I do not find the way.

I have tried the following:

First, create a class associated with EventData and store in a file MyEventData.m:

```
classdef (ConstructorLoad) MyEventData < event.EventData
    properties (Access = public)
        Data = [];
    end
    methods
        function obj=MyEventData(receiveObject)
            obj.Data = receiveObject;
        end
    end
end
```

Next, inside my program.m:

```
% Create the session
Session = daq.createSession('nidaq');

% Add a channel
Channels = addAnalogInputChannel(Session, 'PXI1Slot2', 0, 'Voltage'); 

% Set continuous adquisition
Session.IsContinuous = true;

% Sampling rate
Session.Rate = 1000000;

% in this way two events per second
Session.NotifyWhenDataAvailableExceeds = 500000;

% Add listener
lh=addlistener(Session,'DataAvailable', @(src,event)EventFunction(src,event));

% My counter or any other data to pass to the event
TaskCounter = 0;

% Add my data
notify(Session, 'DataAvailable', MyEventData(TaskCounter);

% Start the session to adquire data
Session.startBackground();
```

When I run this, I get the following error in the line of the notify:

*Event 'DataAvailable' is not defined for class 'event.listener'*

I do not find any way to pass data to the event. I find the Matlab help is quite but regarding this issue.

Comment: After some more investigation I have found that in the classdef I have a mistake in (ConstructOnLoad), an also that the variable name cannot be Data, because is the same name as the standar variable for the samples that uses Matlab. I have change the name to MyData. Now the error message is "No public field MyData exist for class MyEventData.